# Group similar values in multiple lists

Tags: python, list

I have values like this.

```
col1    col2    col3
17.635  8.661   8.636
26.295  27.386  19.524
31.76           27.361
                35.536
```

I want to convert it to like this

```
col1    col2    col3
'--'    8.661   8.636 
17.635  '--'    '--' 
'--'    '--'    19.524 
26.295  '--'    '--' 
'--'    27.386  27.361 
31.76   '--'    '--' 
'--'    '--'    35.536
```

The goal is group similar values which are ± 0.2 with respect to each other. If there is no matching value, add place holder like '--'

first converted individual column to list.

```
in_list = [
    [17.635, 26.295, 31.76], #col 1
    [8.661, 27.386], #col 2
    [8.636, 19.524, 27.361, 35.536] #col 3
]
```

Created reference list to compare with. My values are in the scale of 0.2.

```
ref_list = [x*0.2 for x in range(200)]
```

Then this is long ugly way.

```
placeholder='--'

result = [[] for _ in range(len(input_list)+1)]
for ref in ref_list:
    result[0].append(ref)
    for i, lst in enumerate(input_list):
        append_ref = True
        for item in lst:
            if item not in result[i+1]:
                if ref + 0.2 > item < ref + 0.2:
                    result[i+1].append(item)
                    append_ref = False
                    break
        if append_ref:
            result[i+1].append(placeholder)
final_result = []
for i in range(len(result[0])):
    l = [lst[i] for lst in result]
    if all([x == placeholder for x in l[1:]]):
        pass
    else:
        final_result.append(l)


print(final_result)
#Changed decimal for redability
[
    #ref    col1    col2     col3
    [8.6,   '--',   8.661,  8.636], 
    [17.6,  17.635, '--',   '--'], 
    [19.40, '--',   '--',   19.524], 
    [26.20, 26.295, '--',   '--'], 
    [27.20, '--',   27.386, 27.361], 
    [31.6,  31.76,  '--',   '--'], 
    [35.4,  '--',   '--',   35.536]
]
```

Is there any better way?

Comment: Same question as the last version of the question.  What is the criteria for which column these values should be in?

Comment: The column should remain same. Only the row value should shift.

Comment: @StephenRauch: Please see edit. Did I made any clarification?

Comment: You have still not described using words what the goal is.  I assume I can go through the code and reverse engineer the requirements, but it would be better if these things were explicit.

Comment: first, the description of your problem is not clear, sure in your mind yes but only there, second if you want them to improve your code, SO is not the right place, better publish it in https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 2):

From what I figured, you could shorten your code by filtering out items in `ref_list` first and then for each `ref` you can check if an item exists in that column with the required difference.

**Code:**

```
in_list = [
    [17.635, 26.295, 31.76],  # col 1
    [8.661, 27.386],  # col 2
    [8.636, 19.524, 27.361, 35.536]  # col 3
]


def diff(item, ref):
    return 0 <= item - ref < 0.2


refs = (
    ref for ref in (x * 0.2 for x in range(200)) if any(
        diff(item, ref) for row in in_list for item in row
    )
)

for ref in refs:
    lst = [format(ref, '.2f')]
    for row in in_list:
        item = next((item for item in row if diff(item, ref)), None)
        if item is not None:
            lst.append(item)
        else:
            lst.append('---')
    print lst
```

**Output:**

```
['8.60', '---', 8.661, 8.636]
['17.60', 17.635, '---', '---']
['19.40', '---', '---', 19.524]
['26.20', 26.295, '---', '---']
['27.20', '---', 27.386, 27.361]
['31.60', 31.76, '---', '---']
['35.40', '---', '---', 35.536]
```

Comment: Thanks. surely no direct way.